# Cannot get stripe.js working with my Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

Alright, this is my first question on SO, so bear with me (and feel free to comment on my terrible question formatting, etc.)

I am building a SaaS site for a client using Rails 4 and Stripe. I am following this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?view=comments) (keeping in mind it was written for Rails 3  -- as well as the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) .

I just edited my **subscriptions.js.coffee** file per the railscast instructions. At this point, when I click **subscribe** on my subscriptions/new form I should receive a js alert with the response ID, however, instead I am simply redirected to `http://localhost:3000/subscriptions/X`

I have provided what I believe to be the relevant files, however, I am new to Rails, so if additional information is necessary to answer the question, let me know! Thanks!

I should also add that I have **disabled turbolinks** as some have noted that causing issues.

```
# subscriptions.js.coffee #

jQuery ->  
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))  
  subscription.setupForm()  

subscription =  
  setupForm: ->  
    $('#new_subscription').submit ->  
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)  
      subscription.processCard()  

  processCard: ->  
    card =  
      number: $('#card_number').val()  
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()  
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()  
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()  
    Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)  

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->  
    if status == 200  
      alert(response.id)  
    else  
     alert(response.error.message)

# subscriptions/new.html.erb #

<h1>Signing up for "<%= @subscription.plan.name %>"</h1>
<p>Includes <strong><%= @subscription.plan.business_plans %> Business Plans</strong> for only <strong><%= number_to_currency @subscription.plan.price %></strong> per month!</p>

<%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>
  <% if @subscription.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@subscription.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscription from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @subscription.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
    <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
    <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Subscribe" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

# subscriptions_controller.rb #

class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
    if @subscription.save
      redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def subscription_params
    params.require(:subscription).permit(:plan_id, :email)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit handler:

```
$('#new_subscription').submit ->  
  $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)  
  subscription.processCard()
```

should return `false` or call [`ev.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to keep the form from being submitted:

```
$('#new_subscription').submit (ev) ->
  ev.preventDefault() # <------------------------ This
  $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)  
  subscription.processCard()
  false               # <------------------------ or this.
```

Otherwise you'll call `processCard` which will send off the AJAX call to Stripe but the form will have been submitted to the server and the page refreshed before Stripe can respond.

Once you sort that out, you'll probably end up in a submit loop like in [this other Stripe question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20073360/479863) I answered a few hours ago.

Comment: Thanks so much for you quick response! It's things like SO that give me faith in humanity.

Comment: @mu is too short could you please help me?